# When I Execute the function I get the error message "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function onclick"

Tags: javascript

This is my first time using this site sorry if it's in the wrong form.
When I execute the function I get the error message "Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function onclick"
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<header>
    <link src="Style.css" type="text/css">
    <link src="Js.js" type="text/javascript">
    </header>
<head><img src="logo.jpg">Clubs</head>
  <div>
      <input type="text" id="studentNumber">
      <input type="password" id="studentPassword">
      <button id="submit" onclick="submit();">Submit</button>
      <p id="studentInfo"></p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
      <input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
      <input type="text" id="number" placeholder="Student Number">
      <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="button" id="enter" placeholder="New User" onclick="enter()">
    </div>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
function enter(){
    var pie = document.getElementById("newUser").value + 1;
    var first = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
    var last = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
    var numb = document.getElementById("number").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
}
var newUser = [];
var pie = 0;
var first = [];
    first[0] = studentfirstname;
var last = [];
    last[0] = studentlastname;
var numb = [];
    numb[0]

 = studentnumber;
```

Comment: Which `onclick` event is causing this issue? I'd have to assume it's the one on your `submit` button. Two issues, I don't see a function called `submit` anywhere in your Javascript, and also, try not to use regular reserved keywords as function names (like `submit` and `enter`). They may cause issues if they already exist.

Comment: Whats up with the arrays, why you making a new array for each field?

Comment: If this is your real HTML file you are missing your body tag. Run your source HTML through a validator to find all your errors first.

Comment: Also your header/head tags are backwards.

Comment: There's no `onclick` anywhere in the Javascript you posted. Which line is that error happening on?

Comment: @Barmar Its inline on some html elements.

Comment: HTML attributes don't cause that error.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
<link src="Js.js" type="text/javascript">
```

is not how you import JavaScript. You want

```
<script src="Js.js"></script>
```

The `enter()` function is undefined because your script isn't being loaded at all.

The code in your script, even if successfully imported, won't do anything. The `var` declarations in your `enter()` function hide the external declarations of the global variables.

Answer (score 0):

1. try loading your js like this:

   ```
   <head>
   <link src="Style.css" type="text/css">
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="Js.js"</script>
   </head>
   ```

   instead of

   ```
   <header>
       <link src="Style.css" type="text/css">
       <link src="Js.js" type="text/javascript">
   </header>
   ```
2. your studentfirstname and other similar variables looks like not defined.